# Devise with existing database: 401 Unauthorized using valid password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, activerecord, devise

I am trying to use devise for user authentication of my website. 
It uses an existing User table.

The table has username and password, however when I try to log in, I get the following error:

**Completed 401 Unauthorized in 90ms.**

**Logs:**

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-06 15:50:01 +0530
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+uKE28LrkWW71EHeasDSDCENQogAGODfBc3ZJJLyi9U=", "user"=>{"email"=>"admin@abc.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
 User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'admin@abc.com' LIMIT 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 90ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+uKE28LrkWW71EHeasDSDCENQogAGODfBc3ZJJLyi9U=", "user"=>{"email"=>"admin@abc.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
```

Comment: Are you sure you use valid email and password?

Comment: Yes..the email and password are valid. When I create a new user table, it works. But i want to use an existing table which is in another database. When I do User.first in the console, I see the proper details of the User from the existing table.

Comment: You should try then solutions listed in:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Migration-legacy-database
This probably occurs because passwords in old database are encrypted in other way than devise does it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked! I had forgotten to change the encryption key.

Comment: @user2459261, you should explain what you did as an answer and accept it. Also which version of devise and rails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its solved! 
I changed the encryption key of the rails project in configs/initializers/devise.rb.

Rails version: 3.2.13
Devise version: 2.04

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact problem but only in production (using rails 4 and devise 3).

The solution was to add a domain declaration to the config/initializers/session_store.rb file like this:

```
YourAppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_session', domain: {
  production: 'prpoduction_domain',
  development: 'development_domain'
}.fetch(Rails.env.to_sym, :all)
```

Though it is important that this was changed initially due to adding sub-domains to the application.