# Devise throws 401 unauthorized and redirects only in Production/Staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have an authentication system set up with Devise.

I can successfully login in development mode, but I cannot login a user with valid credentials in staging/production environment.

Can session storage be the cause of this?

This is what I have inside config/initializers/session_store.rb:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_pigo_session'
```

I also added `config.http_authenticatable = false` in config/intitializers/devise.rb

My staging.log file looks like this:

```
  I, [2015-06-10T16:57:20.325304 #3577]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 69.59.28.19 at 2015-06-10 16:57:20 +0400
  I, [2015-06-10T16:57:20.327106 #3577]  INFO -- : Processing by OffersController#index as HTML
  I, [2015-06-10T16:57:20.328034 #3577]  INFO -- : Filter chain halted as #<Proc:0x007fad7d18c5b8@/home/deploy/apps/pigo/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb:71> rendered or redirected
  I, [2015-06-10T16:57:20.328232 #3577]  INFO -- : Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: When you said you "can't" login, do you see any errors or something relevant in the logs?

Comment: Have you given static path by mistake instead of relative path in "after_sign_in_path_for" method?

Comment: @codingaddicted I edited my question with the staging log output

Comment: @TarunJadhwani I haven't overridden that method

Comment: I don't have an idea for the moment, but there are similar questions that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168178/rails-401-unauthorized-when-i-access-action-in-production-only  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960041/devise-with-existing-database-401-unauthorized-using-valid-password

Comment: @codingaddicted I've tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/24885909/1682542 but still doesn't work in staging env. also, I get ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in development when trying to login

Answer (score 0):

If this can help anyone, I faced a similar problem recently. The issue was with the nginx configuration (used as a reverse proxy in my production environment).

Here's what I changed to fix the issue:

```
upstream puma {
  server localhost:3000;
}

server {
  # ...
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; # <== added this line
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }
}
```